# How to compare two lists based on first element and get the matching values into dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

```
list1 = [4356, 'abc']
list2 = {4356: ('5986', '5987'), 6598: ('6593', '2659')}
```

How to compare two lists based on first element (i.e, '4356' element in this case) and get the matching values from list2 into dictionary with 'True' word added?

I need output to be like:

```
output = {'5986':'True', '5987':'True'}
```

Comment: Your `list2` is actually a dictionary.  Is that intentional?

Comment: It was actually in the format of [(4356, '5986'), (4356, '5987'), (6598, '6593'), (6598, '2659')]. I converted that into dictionary for better understanding. @PatrickHaugh

Comment: Using your original list format: `{y: 'True' for x, y in list2 if x in list1}`

Comment: @MosesKoledoye OP wants to only use the first element of `list1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list1 = [4356, 'abc']
list2 = {4356: ('5986', '5987'), 6598: ('6593', '2659')}

output = {x: True for x in list2[list1[0]]}
print(output)  # {'5986': True, '5987': True}
```

Or, using the `list2` from your comment:

```
list1 = [4356, 'abc']
list2 = [(4356, '5986'), (4356, '5987'), (6598, '6593'), (6598, '2659')]

output = {val: True for key, val in list2 if key == list1[0]}
print(output)  # {'5986': True, '5987': True}
```